# Working with MARC file

Tags: c#, xml, marc

I'm having a database project for a library. Nearly all the book information in the library is available on the library of congress which provides free downloadable of book records that store in *.mrc file (MARC). I am required to retrieve those records from the MARC file and import to my database. Can anybody provide me a framework that can implement for reading, manipulating, outputting and converting bibliographic records in the MARC format? or else I can at lease convert MARC format to XML format? Notice that I'm using .net plate form to develop my application which are c# and sql server.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.csharpmarc.net/ yet?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different options listed on the Code4lib wiki's [Working with MARC](http://wiki.code4lib.org/index.php/Working_with_MaRC) page:

- CSharpMARC
- MARCLibrary

There's a third one there that was under development (MARC.NET) but seems to be largely abandoned.

Answer (score -2):

MARCEdit also has a library. URL: http://oclc.org/developer/gallery/marcedit.en.html